# How to launch 2 applications in Flex mobile?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flex4.6

I am building 2 applications in flex mobile.
These applications should communicate together (a kind of chat system).

My problem is that I cannot run 2 applications in Flex Builder at the same same: any time I launch one instance, the other instance is killed.

Is there a way to launch 2 applications?

Answer (score 0):

You can't launch them both in debug mode; but you should be able to launch one in debug mode and one in "normal" mode.

If you create a separate workspace for each project; you should be able to launch one application per workspace.

Comment: NO ! 
event with 2 projetcs, I can just run once instance !

Comment: I don't understand your follow up comment.

Comment: I mean: you cannot run 2 instances. I tried in debug mode or normal mode. This works prefectly for SWF project, buit not for mobile project

Comment: @user300675, that's because ADL cannot run multiple application instances. I'd probably setup another development machine (VM would do) and run another debug version. Other than that, you can just deploy one app to a device and use the debug version on your development machine to debug the current session between the two applications.